# Access Laravel HTTP client status code in catch block

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, guzzle

I need to be able to access the status code and response time in my `catch` block as not every error from the HTTP client results in no status code.

I've tried the following:

```php
/**
* HTTP type
*
* @return object
*/
public function checkWithHttp($url, $timeout)
{
    try {
        $startResponseTime = microtime(true);
        $response = Http::withHeaders([
            'User-Agent' => 'Mozilla/5.0+(compatible; DomainMonitor/2.0; https://domain-monitor.io/)'
        ])->timeout($timeout)->get($url);
        $stopResponseTime = microtime(true);

        $responseTime = ($stopResponseTime - $startResponseTime) * 1000;

        return [
            'response_time' => round($responseTime),
            'code' => $response->getStatusCode(),
            'ok' => $response->ok(),
            'json' => $response->json(),
            'headers' => $response->headers()
        ];
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        return [
            'response_time' => round($responseTime),
            'code' => $response->getStatusCode(),
            'ok' => false,
            'json' => null,
            'headers' => null
        ];
    }
}
```

But the results in `$responseTime` being undefined.

Comment: you need to declare  $startResponseTime outside the try block

Comment: How you expect that responseTime is set if it's after the statement that throws the exception? You should copy the calculation line to the catch block.

Comment: How can I access the status code from the request in my catch?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the estimated time the request was being transferred by the handler via [`getTransferTime()`](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/blob/7.4.1/src/TransferStats.php#L109) :

```
$response = Http::withHeaders(['User-Agent' => 'Mozilla/5.0+(compatible; DomainMonitor/2.0; https://domain-monitor.io/)'])
    ->timeout($timeout)
    ->get($url);
$responseTime = $response->transferStats->getTransferTime();
$return = [
    'response_time' => round($responseTime),
    'code' => $response->getStatusCode(),
    'ok' => $response->successful(),
    'json' => $response->json(),
    'headers' => $response->headers()
];
```

FYI, unlike Guzzle's default behavior, Laravel's HTTP client wrapper **does not throw exceptions on client or server errors (`400` and `500` level responses from servers)**. So, you don't need to make a `try-catch`. You may determine if one of these errors was returned using the `successful`, `clientError`, or `serverError` methods.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```php
try {
    $startResponseTime = microtime(true);
    $response = Http::withHeaders([
        'User-Agent' => 'Mozilla/5.0+(compatible; DomainMonitor/2.0; https://domain-monitor.io/)'
    ])->timeout($timeout)->get($url);
    $stopResponseTime = microtime(true);

    $responseTime = ($stopResponseTime - $startResponseTime) * 1000;

    if($response->successful()){
        return [
            'response_time' => round($responseTime),
            'code' => $response->getStatusCode(),
            'ok' => $response->ok(),
            'json' => $response->json(),
            'headers' => $response->headers()
        ];

    }else{

        return [
            'response_time' => round($responseTime),
            'code' => $response->getStatusCode(),
            'ok' => false,
            'json' => null,
            'headers' => null
        ];

    }

} catch (\Exception $e) {
    return [
        'response_time' => 0,
        'code' => 0,
        'ok' => false,
        'json' => null,
        'headers' => null,
        'message' => $e->getMessage(), //get exception message
    ];
}
```